# How do you trigger an event when clicking outside of your form? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

As you can see I tried using the leave trigger but that didn't quite hit the mark does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in regards.

[image]

Comment: Nice project name ^^

Comment: Maybe you could try [Form.Deactivated](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SteveZ: "Maybe you could try [Form.Deactivated](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate?view=netframework-4.8)"

Answer (score 0):

Won't LosingFocus or LostFocus events do the trick ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus?view=netframework-4.8